# Scala Spray serve a file attachment

Tags: scala, spray

How do you serve a file attachment from spray.  Do I need to set individual content headers, or is there a better way of doing it.  If so, how best to handle content length given compression maybe enabled.

Comment: Under serve file attachment you mean upload file to Spray server?

Comment: No, the file is the response:Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myFile.pptx

Answer (score 2):

Ok I just needed to add my own custom headers, content length seems to take care of itself.

```
respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`) {
  respondWithHeader(HttpHeaders.`Content-Disposition`.apply("attachment", Map("filename" -> "myFile.pptx"))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I did do such stuff myself, there is a [demo service](https://github.com/whataboutbob/spray-file-upload/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/examples/DemoService.scala#L38) on GH with example. The only moment, you can extract filename with std directives like:

```
val fileName = headerValuePF {
 case `Content-Disposition`(toe, params) =>
   params.get("filename")
}
```

From that demo it looks like no headers required, all files info can be extracted from BodyPart and additional info from Content-Disposition. I didn't such services myself, so if this wouldn't help you please notify in the comments.

Comment: That looks the other way around, but I was able to solve it with setting the headers directly